# Group Z/3Z Proof of Subgroup.

Tags: equivalence-relations, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I am looking at the quotient group G = Z/3Z.  The equivalence classes are:

[0] = {...,0,3,6,...}

[1] = {...,1,4,7,...}

[2] = {...,2,5,8,...}

I want to prove [0] is a normal subgroup, N, by showing gng<sup>-1</sup> = n' ∈ N for g ∈ G and n ∈ N.  G is abelian so gg<sup>-1</sup>n = n' ∈ N.  The identity element 0 is also in G so I should be able to write 0.0<sup>-1</sup>n = n'.  How do I interpret 0.0<sup>-1</sup>?

Comment: The group is additive. So you show normality by proving $(-g)+n+(-g)\in N$ etc. The group is also Abelian.

Comment: OK.   First, did you mean to have a minus in front of both g's?.  My first thought was that since the inverse of the identity is the identity then 0.0<sup>-1</sup> =  0.  Therefore, this would give 0n = n' = 0.  This is also consistent with 0n = n0.  However, I am still not sure about this because as you point out the identity is being used multiplicatively and not additively..

Comment: It's too late to edit my comment. You might also see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/